# Проблема в нахождении минимального элемента среди максимальных элементов столбцов матрицы

Tags: java

Здрaвcтвуйтe, есть проблема. Я уже несколько часов пытаюсь докопаться до истины, но чувствую, что просто чего-то не понимаю.
Есть матрица и в ней **среди максимальных элементов столбцов** нужно найти ***минимальный***, а **среди минимальных элементов строк** ***максимальный*** элемент ***(оба с координатами)***. Так вот, если для активного массива этот код работает, то для остальных двух считает неверно. И если я заставлю код считать правильно, например, для 3-го массива, то для 2-го решение ломается.
 Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  int max, min;
  int minmax = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int maxmin = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;

  /*int[][] array = {{1,-3,-2},
                   {0,5,4},
                   {2,3,2}}; */
  int[][] array = {{3,9,2,1},
                   {7,8,5,6},
                   {4,7,3,5},
                   {5,6,1,7}};
  /*int[][] array = {{3,1,2,5},
                     {2,0,0,3},
                     {-3,-5,-5,-2},
                     {0,-2,-2,1}}; */

     System.out.println("Матрица чисел: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
            }

//-------------------------------------------------------  
  System.out.println("\nMAX по столбцам: ");
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    max = array[0][i];
      for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++) {              
          if(max < array[j][i]){
              max = array[j][i];

           if (minmax > max){
                minmax = max;
                x1 = j+1;
                y1 = i+1;
           }
          } 
      }       
      System.out.print(max + "  ");

    }
    System.out.println("\nВерхняя чистая цена игры (MinMax) = " + minmax + "("+x1 +";"+y1+")");

//------------------------------------------------------- 
System.out.println("\nMIN по строкам: ");   
        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++){ 
          min = array[j][0];
          for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {          
              if(min > array[j][i]){
                 min=array[j][i];

                if (maxmin < min){
                     maxmin = min;
                     x2 = j+1;
                     y2 = i+1; 
                }   
          } 

       }
         System.out.print(min + "  ");
    }
      System.out.println("\nНижняя чистая цена игры (MaxMin) = " + maxmin + "("+x2 +";"+y2+")");

//-------------------------------------------------------      
    }
```

Comment: вот тут не понял, какая разница между поиском минимального в максимальных и обычным поискам минимального?

Comment: Я делаю проект для решения чистых стратегий теории игр. Здесь это необходимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот нахождение максимума среди минимумов строк (другое - аналогично):

```
int maxMin = 0;
int iMaxMin = -1;
int jMaxMin = -1;

System.out.println("\nMIN по строкам: ");   
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{ 
  int min = array[i][0];
  int jMin = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) 
  {  
    if (array[i][j] < min) 
    {
      min = array[i][j];
      jMin = j;
    } 
  }
  if (i == 0 || min > maxMin) 
  {
    maxMin = min;
    iMaxMin = i;
    jMaxMin = jMin;
  }
}
```

```js
function rowMaxMin(array) {
  var maxMin;
  var iMaxMin;
  var jMaxMin;

  console.log("MAX-MIN по строкам: ");
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var min = array[i][0];
    var jMin = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] < min) {
        min = array[i][j];
        jMin = j;
      }
    }
    if (i == 0 || min > maxMin) {
      maxMin = min;
      iMaxMin = i;
      jMaxMin = jMin;
    }
  }
  console.log(`array[${iMaxMin}][${jMaxMin}]=${maxMin}`);
}

var arr1 = [
  [1,-3,-2],
  [0, 5, 4],
  [2, 3, 2]
];
var arr2 = [
  [3,9,2,1],
  [7,8,5,6],
  [4,7,3,5],
  [5,6,1,7]
];
var arr3 = [
  [ 3, 1, 2, 5],
  [ 2, 0, 0, 3],
  [-3,-5,-5,-2],
  [ 0,-2,-2, 1]
];
rowMaxMin(arr1);
rowMaxMin(arr2);
rowMaxMin(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить пару строчек

```
...
if (minmax > max) minmax = max;
System.out.print(max + "  ");
```

и

```
...
if (maxmin < min) maxmin = min;
System.out.print(min + "  ");
```

Получалось, если изначально максимальный элемент был первым в каждом столбце, то условие просто не проходило никогда и значение было заданное при инициализации. В другом поиске тоже такая ошибка есть, можно проверить если задать данные вроде

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
```

Перепишите лучше. Не факт что даже сейчас оно работает правильно

Answer (score 0):

И так разобьём задачу на несколько подзадач) нам нужно хранить позицию и значение, тогда создадим такой класс :3 Хоба

```
class ValuePosition {
    private int value;
    private int i;
    private int j;

    ValuePosition(int value, int i, int j) {
        this.value = value;
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }
}
```

Теперь нам нужно найти максимальное в столбце, проще простого)

```
public ValuePosition findMaxColumn(int[][] target, int column) {
    ValuePosition max = new ValuePosition(target[0][column], 0, column); // Представим что первый элемент столба column максимальный
    for (int i = 1; i < target.length; i++)
        if (max.getValue() < target[i][column])
            max = new ValuePosition(target[i][column], i, column);
    return max;
}
```

Так как мы сделали функцию поиска максимального, можем сделать поиск минимального проще:)
Что-то вроде...

```
public ValuePosition findMinInMaxColumns(int[][] target) {
    ValuePosition min = findMaxColumn(target, 0); // Находим максимальный элемент первого столбца и представляем, что он минимальный
    for (int i = 1; i < target[0].length; i++) // Начинаем с 1 так как представили что минимальный это максимальный из первого столбца
        if (min.getValue() > findMaxColumn(target, i).getValue())
            min = findMaxColumn(target, i);
    return min;
}
```

Вот мы и закончили половину)
Осталось сделать поиск минимального в строке и максимального среди строк:)
Минимальный как-то так)

```
public ValuePosition findMinRow(int[][] target, int row) {
    ValuePosition min = new ValuePosition(target[row][0], row, 0); // Представим что первый элемент строки row минимальный
    for (int i = 1; i < target[0].length; i++)
        if (min.getValue() > target[row][i])
            min = new ValuePosition(target[row][i], row, i);
    return min;
}
```

Иии на финишной прямой)

```
public ValuePosition findMaxInMinRows(int[][] target) {
    ValuePosition max = findMinRow(target, 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < target.length; i++)
        if (max.getValue() < findMinRow(target, i).getValue())
            max = findMinRow(target, i);
    return max;
}
```

Вооот и всё) Чтобы использовать методы нужно добавить их в главный класс с модификатором **static**, либо создать отдельный класс) 
Результат получается с помощью методов **getValue()**, **getI()**, **getJ()** класса **ValuePosition** :) Удачи